# cant add account on gnome-online-accounts

Tags: 16.04, gnome

Im trying to add an account to gnome-online-accounts but the button is disabled (gray) and it wont let me click to add account.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and installed by doing apt-get install "gnome-control-center gnome-online-accounts" and tried to install gnome too using "apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop" without any success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It is an issue with the default NetworkManager configuration.

By default, NetworkManager won’t touch the default wired ethernet connection because it’s listed in /etc/network/interfaces. As a consequence, it thinks the system is “offline”. I think this is greying out the “add” buttons. (It also breaks Evolution.)

Performing the config changes listed in https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager in the section **Enabling Interface Management** causes both of these problems to be fixed.

This should probably be the default configuration.

Reference: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=818932

Answer (score 0):

Miquel Jabalera's answer that worked for me:

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

I edited the line after `[ifupdown]`:

- from:    `managed=false`
- to:    `managed=true`

Started working for me.